# Assembly memory addresses (8051)

Tags: assembly, memory-address

I would like to understand how the following memory address range was obtained. Screenshot is from Mazidi's 8051 embedded programming in C and Assembly.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D7E3E434DBBB2938!1171&authkey=!AE81hcdvywC_6js&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Comment: If you mean the `0x0000-0xFFFF` that's simply because `2^16=0x10000`, ie. the range representable by 16 bits which is a given.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Got it. I understand that addressable memory is 2^x where x = num. of address lines. 2^16 = 65536 -> 10000h. So basically FFFF is just us maxing out the possible value for a 16 bit address. Thank you.